# SwiftUI popover example does not look like the picture shown in documentation

Tags: ios, swiftui, popover

[This page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/popover(ispresented:attachmentanchor:arrowedge:content:)) of the SwiftUI documentation presents the following example with an accompanying image showing the expected result:

```
struct PopoverExample: View {
    @State private var isShowingPopover = false


    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Popover") {
            self.isShowingPopover = true
        }
        .popover(isPresented: $isShowingPopover) {
            Text("Popover Content")
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Result image in SwiftUI documentation:

[image]

If I copy exactly the same code and run it in my simulator I get the following result:

My result:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a known problem? Or is the documentation rather imprecise and there is actually still code missing in the example?

Comment: [This](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655217) might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshot shown in the documentation is probably taken on a larger device like an iPad, with non-compact size classes.

When the screen is small, popovers are automatically shown as sheets. To change this, you can use [`presentationCompactAdaptation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/presentationcompactadaptation(_:)) to override this, though this is only available since iOS 16.4.

```
.popover(isPresented: $isShowingPopover) {
    Text("Popover Content")
        .padding()
        .presentationCompactAdaptation(.popover)
}
```